# Java+MySql- Stuck at creation of setup file

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans

i am creating a simple desktop database application  in netbeans platform by using java+mysql languages for a shop. But finally i just stuck at the creation of setup file of them.So programmers let me know how i can create setup file or exe file for my program including database(i know how to create exe file of non database java application).

1. should i install mysql on customer computer??
2. Is there any software that will make setup file of both java+mysql file??

Comment: But i think we should create extra java classes for creating sqlite database and tables right??

Comment: What you guys will do in the case of vb or vb.net??

Comment: @AmeenAmi No. SQLite behaves like MySQL. The only "great" difference is that while MySQL is a server with a DB engine, SQLite is a full DB engine and doesn't require a server installed on the computer. The syntax is the same, and you use Statements and Prepared Statements just as you do with MySQL.

Comment: But where i can create tables in sqlite??only through programming itself right??

Comment: @AmeenAmi Yes. And that's how you should do it. If the database is on the user's computer, you need to create your tables, you can't expect the user to do it for you. If you don't want to have to worry about creating tables in the program, use a server over the internet.

Comment: Ok.can you please tell me,What you guys will do in the case of vb or vb.net to deploy both front end and backend with single setup installation like java+sqlite or derby combination for a simple desktop database application??